# Where is the documentation for Passport's isAuthenicated Method?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I was following a course on Node and I came across the instructor checking if a user was authenticated with Passport by calling `req.isAuthenticated()`. I'm not really a fan of just blindly following a tutorial and when I tried to find some documentation on the official Passport website. I couldn't find anything regarding the method. My question is if I wanted to find more methods like this. Is there something I'm missing and just don't know about Passport because I checked all over the site and couldn't find any documentation regarding this method?

Answer (score 0):

[There is](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a892b9dc54dce34b7170ad5d73d8ccfba87f4fcf/lib/passport/http/request.js#L74) all you looking for. Imao all what needed to know about `isAuthenticated` is:

```
app.use( ["/admin", "/protected"], ( req, res, next ) => {
  if( req.isAuthenticated() ) {
    next();
  } else {
    const error = new Error('Permission denied!')
    error.status = 403
    return next(error)
  }
})
```